# Can we use 'most' with a non-collective countable singular noun?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use "most of" before a non-collective countable singular noun?

Comment: *I ate **most** of the apple.* If that's not what you mean, it's not clear what you do. But if that *is* what you mean, I'm curious what sounds wrong about it to you.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean; I asked because I could not find an example of that in some dictionaries;

Comment: Not finding examples of something in a dictionary is seldom a good indicator of what's actually acceptable grammar. Although checking it is good, if you don't find it, you can try googling a simple phrase or two as another kind of check.